# ASP.NET MVC 2: SPROC resturn result?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I can't figure out how to get the returned data from the SPROC that I call:

```
public string LoginParty(string UserName, string LoginPin)
{
    var result = db.spPartyLogin(UserName, LoginPin);

    return result.ToString; // I wish
}
```

I'd like to know how to retrieve the result of any SPROC that I call. In this case, I'm only getting one result, an email address or a 0 if the credentials are incorrect ... and `result.ToString` doesn't work.

SPROC:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPartyLogin] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @UserName varchar(50),
    @LoginPin varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value varchar(50)
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Select statements for procedure here
    SELECT @value = EmailAddress FROM Party
    WHERE UserName = @UserName AND LoginPin = @LoginPin;

    SELECT ISNULL(@value,0)

END
```

As you can see, in this case, I'm returning the EmailAddress or 0. I want to capture that returned result. I don't know how many other ways I can describe what I'm trying to do...

Comment: I want to be able to retrieve the result... and send it back to the controller so I can do something with it. `result.ToString` doesn't actually collect the result and convert it `ToString`

Comment: Is this a Linq2Sql stored proc?  Is it returning a resultset or what?  If you're returning one string, try declaring the stored proc with an out parameter.  Put a breakpoint there and examine the result.

Comment: What exactly is the type of the variable db? If we know that, we have some idea of the database access system you're using. Where did this variable come from? Also, a definition of the sproc you're trying to use would be helpful as well.

Comment: Linq. My SPROC returns the result... there's nothing special here. I just want to see the resulting return information.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Libq2Sql would create a new type and return an IEnumerable of that type.  Since your single result row has a column without a name, I'm not sure what it will do.  Examine your result in the debugger to see what you have.  If EmailAddress isn't an integer then you shouldn't use the integer 0 as a replacement if it is null.  You could use a bkank string or even allow it to return null.

If you can't see the address when watching result in the debugger, try declaring it as an out parameter or assigning a column name in the result:

```
SELECT ISNULL(@value,'') AS EmailAddress

ALTER PROCEDURE spPartyLogin
    @Username VARCHAR(50),
    @LoginPin VARCHAR(50),
    @EmailAddress VARCHAR(50) out
```

You'll need to delete and add back the proc to get Linq2Sql to see the changes and regenerate the code either way.